# Asking a question while logging in at the same time with OpenID drops question

Tags: bug, status-completed

I wrote my question on superuser.com, and before I clicked "Ask Your Question" at the bottom, I realized I wasn't logged in yet because it asked me for my OpenID.  I typed it in and clicked Ask Your Question.  It logged me in, but then I saw the same Question screen, but with my question erased.  Checking my profile page confirmed that my question was not posted and instead just vanished.

Perhaps superuser.com has a bug where logging in while posting a question at the same time loses the question?

Comment: Yeah , that happened with me too, status completed? does that mean bug acknowledged or fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the build released tonight.

Comment: Confirmed.  It worked.